# Authenticate server to server communication

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, oauth-2.0

I am new in authentication/authorization. I need to expose some authenticated apis to be consumed by third parties (server to server). I read how I can do this and figured out that a good option is to use oauth2.

I want to implement this using java with spring boot. My first problem is how to generate client id and client secret. Can you help me with some advice/materials to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Oauth2 is about authorization, not authentication. If you have a single api which you want to expose to others, you most probably don't need the complexity. Oauth2 is primarily for the usecase when you have an app that wants to access a 3rd party resource on behalf of your users. Say you want to post to a user's facebook wall. For plain authentication, look at much simpler options like api keys or even client certs. And by the way oauth2 with identity ("authentication" if you like) is openid connect, but it sounds like you don't need that either.

Answer (score 0):

For generating the Client-Id and Secret, [this guide](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/) might be useful.

In all cryptographic affairs, try to find solid / well tested libraries, as mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Client id and client secret is just a simple login / password pair. Usual constraint apply, just ensure that your secret is not too simple.

As there is only two party implied, the oauth flow is very simple ([client credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)).

One server (the client) will consume resources on the other one (the resource server `@EnableWebSecurity`, `@EnableResourceServer`) using an access token acquired against the authorizations server beforehand. The resource server may also act as the authorization server (`@EnableAuthorizationServer`). The client is annotated using `@EnableOAuth2Client`.

If communication is bidirectionnal, both "server" must be resource server and client (and so have its own client id / secret pair), the authorization server may be independent or hosted by one or both server.